# KeyError when using panda's assign function

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have data frame below and I wish to create new variables "profit_loss" and "profit_margin" based on revenue & budget.

```
        revenue     budget
0      1513528810  150000000
1       378436354  150000000
2       295238201  110000000
3      2068178225  200000000
4      1506249360  190000000
```

I try to create new variables with pandas [assign()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html) method but I got error below.

```
d.assign(profit_loss = (d['revenue'] - d['budget']), 
         profit_loss_margin = (d['profit_loss'] * 100 / d['revenue']), 
         financial_status = d['profit_loss'].apply(lambda num: 'Profit-Making' if num > 0 else 'Loss- 
         Making'))

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)    2895                 return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)    2896             except KeyError as err:
-> 2897                 raise KeyError(key) from err    2898     2899         if tolerance is not None:

KeyError: 'profit_loss'
```

However, code below works just fine.

```
d.assign(profit_loss = (d['revenue'] - d['budget']))
```

Please advise did I make any mistake in previous codes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need `lambda` for working with new created column like here `profit_loss`:

```
df = d.assign(profit_loss = (d['revenue'] - d['budget']), 
              profit_loss_margin = lambda x: (x['profit_loss'] * 100 / x['revenue']), 
              financial_status =  lambda x: x['profit_loss'].apply(lambda num: 'Profit-Making' if num > 0 else 'Loss- Making'))

print (df)
      revenue     budget  profit_loss  profit_loss_margin financial_status
0  1513528810  150000000   1363528810           90.089386    Profit-Making
1   378436354  150000000    228436354           60.363216    Profit-Making
2   295238201  110000000    185238201           62.741949    Profit-Making
3  2068178225  200000000   1868178225           90.329654    Profit-Making
4  1506249360  190000000   1316249360           87.385887    Profit-Making
```

Comment: thanks. it works. I though I can skip the "lambda" to simplify my codes.

Answer (score 0):

You are assigning the df variable 'profit_loss' and trying to use it to assign new variables in the same call.  Python is going to resolve all of the parameters before calling the function.  So when it tries to resolve `d['profit_loss']` in your second and third parameter, it doesn't exist yet because `assign` hasn't been called yet.  Try

```
d.assign(profit_loss = (d['revenue'] - d['budget']))
d.assign(profit_loss_margin = (d['profit_loss'] * 100 / d['revenue']), 
         financial_status = d['profit_loss'].apply(lambda num: 'Profit-Making' if num > 0 else 'Loss-Making'))
```